# Override ejabberd/xmpp login process

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, exmpp

I wonder if there's a simple way to override the login process of ejabberd or exmpp.
What I need is to execute some custom code on users login and only return a 'login success' when this execution is done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In ejabberd, there is mechanism called external auth where you can implement your own authentication code.

Look at this page for the example:
http://www.ejabberd.im/extauth